# C++ - Passing in a vector and return a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Sorry for the noob question, but say for example, I already have an Excel add-in written in C++ that takes a single number and return the square of the number (say inputNum and outputNum where outputNum = inputNum^2) and now I would need to modify the function such that the input is a 1xn vector and the output is a vector of same size with the numbers squared, what would I need to modify in order to have it work? Say for example, do I need to change the input to be a pointer since C++ does not take a vector directly as a native type (unlike the double in the original square function).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and the results?

Comment: Are you saying the Excel add-ins must have native types as parameters? If that is the case then you're going to have to write a function that takes a pointer to the vector data and the size of the vector as parameters.

Comment: You declare the types of the parameters to Excel when you register the function.  But they are all C types---it's a C API.  For anything but scalars and strings, there's an Excel specific struct `XLOper` which is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) function is a nice way do do this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

double processElement(double e) {
    return e * e;
}

std::vector<double> processAllElements(const std::vector<double>& in) {
    // The output vector must be constructed to be the same size as the input.
    std::vector<double> out(in.size(), 0);

    // Process each element in the input vector into the output vector.
    // (input is unchanged)
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin(), &processElement);
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> in;
    in.push_back(1);
    in.push_back(2);

    std::vector<double> out = processAllElements(in);

    std::cout << out[0] << "," << out[1];
}
```

If you are dealing with raw pointers to buffers of values, you can still use `std::transform`

```
int main() {
    const int n = 3;
    double in[] = {1,2,3};
    double out[n];

    std::transform(in, in+n, out, &processElement);

    std::cout << out[0] << "," << out[1];
}
```

But if your vector size is not known at compile time, you're much better off using std::vector to manage memory for you.

Comment: How does this help him interface with the Excel C API (which doesn't know `std::vector`, obviously)?

Comment: Good reuse of `processElement` by `std::transform` without explicit iteration.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I guess I got mislead by the tags on the question which are `C++` and `vector`. I'll leave the answer for what it's worth as a possible implementation, but you're right, it doesn't help with the Excel API question (which I think could have been stated more clearly.) -- Upvoted your answer.

Comment: He could have specified the problem a bit more clearly.  But I'm not sure just how much he understands the difference between C++ and the Excel API---"since C++ does not take a vector as a native type" makes me wonder: C++ doesn't require arguments to be native types.  (Nor does C, for that matter, and the Excel interface uses some non-native types, like `XLOper`.)

Answer (score 3):

*"I already have an Excel add-in written in C++ that takes a single number and return the square of the number"*

So let's say you have function:

```
int processElement(int e) {
    ...
}
```

*"now I would need to modify the function such that the input is a 1xn vector and the output is a vector of same size"*

to use it for `std::vector<int>` you can wrap this function:

```
void processVector(std::vector<int>& v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        v[i] = processElement(v[i]);
}
```

Note that to modify something, you don't need to pass it to function by value and return it. You can pass it by reference.

Comment: The Excel API is C, so he can't use `std::vector`.  He must use types which Excel understands.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Since he hasn't provided any code nor specific details, I answered based solely on the question.

Comment: He did say he had an Excel add-in.  But he does seem to be a little confused as to what is C++, and what is the Excel API (which is pure C).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but you'll probably have to go the Oper route.
(That's what we do for almost everything anyway.)  Basically,
you'll have to download the Excel XLL SDK
(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20199
for Excel 2010, but a lot is compatible with older
versions—you probably have this somewhere already, since
you've certainly called `xlfRegister`).
In it, you'll find an include file `XLCALL.h` (or something like
that—I'm not at the office where I have all of the
information), which defines a struct `XLOper` or `XLOper12` (the
first with `char*` for strings, the second with `wchar_t*`), and some
`#define` specifying what is in it.  You'll have to declare your
function as taking a pointer to this struct, and returning it.
(`P` or `Q`, depending on whether you want to use `char` or
`wchar_t` for strings.) You'll then have to parse the
input: was it a table (look at struct member `xltype`), and if
so, for each cell, was it a number.  Similarly, you'll have to
create an XLOper with your data, and return a pointer to it.

There's a lot of documentation at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687883%28v=office.14%29.aspx.
It's not perfect, but it should cover most of the usual cases.
(It's better than you'll find for a lot of things.)

FWIW: The signature of your function would be;

```
XLOper* myFunction( XLOper* tableIn );
```

I can't find an on-line copy of `XLCALL.h`, and I don't have all
of the macros memorized, so I can't go too much into details,
but roughly, you'll have to start by testing whether
`tableIn->xltype` specifies an array or not; depending on the
requirements, you will either return an error or treat it as a
1x1 array if it doesn't.  If it's an array, `tableIn->var.array`
will contain the number of rows and columns, and a pointer to
the actual data (which will be a rows*columns single dimension
array of `XLOper`).  For each element of the array, verify that
it is numeric (again, testing `xltype`), and extracting the
numeric data from the field `var.num`.